# Element going behind background?

Tags: html, css, z-index

I've got an element that is placing itself (and by extension all its children) behind its corresponding section's background.  I haven't had this issue with any other elements on the page, or even within the same section.  I have a background-color set on it inline just to make sure that's what's going on.  It's happening in all browsers.  Thanks for any help that can be provided.

```
<div id="homepage_servicesstrip">
    <div id="homepage_web_drops_wrap" style="background-color:red;">
    </div>
</div>

    #homepage_servicesstrip {
        background:url('home/images/gradient-services-background.png');
        background-size: auto 100%;
        position:absolute;
        margin-top:0px;
        width:100%;
        height:1050px;
        z-index:1;
    }
    #homepage_web_drops_wrap {
        position:absolute;
        margin-top:60%;
        margin-left:10%;
        height:500px;
        width:80%;
        z-index:60;
    }
```

Comment: You've don't have to use `z-index`, moreover `positioning` is bad too

Comment: @[Mr. ]Bojangles: It would be advisable.

Comment: @Mr.Alien: I've been using z-index just to keep everything straight if I move stuff around later.  Is there anything about that that will cause malfunction?  And what's wrong with the positioning?

Comment: @Mr.Lavalamp You don't need `z-index` as your document will be in normal flow, so don't use it unless required

Comment: If I were to move one of the elements above another in the HTML for whatever reason later the z-index would preserve the element order on the page, would it not?

Answer (score 0):

The z-index is calculated on siblings first, then on children. e.g.
HTML

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="one box"></div>
</div>
<div class="box">
    <div class="two box"></div>
</div>
<div class="box">
    <div class="three box"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
   .box {
       z-index:1;
   }
   .two {
       z-index:1000000;
    }
```

`.two` won't be above `.three` because `.three's` parent is above `.two's` parent.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pavloschris/5tLrz/)

Comment: In my case though, the child is falling behind its own parent. :/

Comment: @Mr.Lavalamp Is there a live example somewhere?